# Need to show time in "hh:mm:ss" format in angular 6

Tags: angular6, time-format, angular2-custom-pipes

We have a response of time in below format like,

```
"time": "05:36:38.088"
```

or

```
"time": "05:36:38+088"
```

We need to show it in "hh:mm:ss" or "hh:mm".

I tried to convert it by using split and if - else conditions,
But as both format will need diff splits, so searching for custom pipe to handle both conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **date pipe** for display time or date in specific format. For more documentation please refer [this](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) link.

In your case, you can bind the time in html like

```
{{time | date: 'shortTime'}}
```

or

```
{{time | date: 'mediumTime'}}
```